# Kinesis cross account acess using java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I want to write a Java process that will use STS to assume a role in account A read from Kinesis, then send the events into a Kinesis stream in account B. How can I achieve that, as currently it is not supported by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create two Kinesis clients.

For account A, call STS, get new credentials, then create the Kinesis client using those credentials.

For account B, create a Kinesis client using credentials from account B.

Your application will then read from Kinesis using the first client, and write to Kinesis using the second client.